# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client in nodejs with express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling, node-modules

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:400:5) the error was occuirng again and again also tried try catch can anyone say how to solve it an its reasons?

```
            try {
                resultset[0].json = JSON.parse(resultset[0].json);
                return res.json({
                    success: true,
                    data: resultset,
                    code: 200
                });
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("Error parsing JSON string" + err);
                return res.json({
                    success: true,
                    msg: "json format was wrong",
                    code: 200
                });
         
        }
    }
```

i also tried this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you?

`res.json()` calls `res.end()` internally and you can't call another `res.json()` after the session ended.
It can't be said exactly without seeing the whole code but it seems that there is a code snippet that calls `res.json()` without `return` command above the  code you provided here.

Hope this might help you.